# Create JSON file using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to create a JSON file by executing the following command:

```sh
jq --arg greeting world '{"hello":"$greeting"}' > file.json
```

This command stuck without any input. While

```sh
jq -n --arg greeting world '{"hello":"$greeting"}' > file.json
```

doesn't parse correctly. I'm just wondering is really possible to create a JSON file.

Comment: `jq -n --arg greeting world '{"hello":$greeting}' > file.json`

Comment: @JeffMercado as far as you know is possible to have something like `'{"hello":$greeting-for-you}'`

Comment: Well it's not valid jq syntax so that wouldn't work. We have a variable `greeting` that has the string value `"world"`. You access that variable value using `$greeting`. I don't know what your intentions are with the `-for-you` part, but you could do quite a bit, as long as you use the correct syntax to express it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So your code doesn't work because included the variable inside double quotes which gets treated as string. That is why it is not working

As @Jeff Mercado, pointed out the solution is

```
jq -n --arg greeting world '{"hello":$greeting}' > file.json
```

About the `-` in a name. This is actually possible. But as of now this is not available in released version of jq. If you compile the master branch of jq on your system. There is a new variable called `$ARGS.named` which can be used to access the information.

I just compiled and check the below command and it works like a charm

```
./jq -n --arg name-is tarun '{"name": $ARGS.named["name-is"]}'
{
  "name": "tarun"
}
```

Comment: While that may work for arguments passed in from command line, do you know if the same facilities are available for variables in general? i.e., does something like this exist: `1 as $["some-var"] | $["some-var"] | $VARS.named["some-var"]` I haven't looked at the source or grammars for a while now so I have no idea what's coming up.

Comment: On a personal note, I don't think that mechanism is very great. It seems like a round-about way to ease restrictions on variable names. It's a solution for a non-problem IMHO. There are restrictions on variable names for a reason, to make designing the language and using it easier. The same restrictions don't apply to object key names so those mechanisms should exist there.

Comment: @JeffMercado - The loophole that Tarun describes could be viewed as a bug that might one day be fixed!

Comment: @peak: by loophole, are you referring to the dash in the name? I found the [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1345) (and [PR](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1346)) that prompted the addition of the `$ARGS` object. I guess the acceptance of the dash was an unintended consequence.

Answer (score 11):

`$ARGS` provides access to named (`--arg name value`) and positional (`--args one two three`) arguments from the jq command line, and allows you to build up objects easily & safely.

Named arguments:

```
$ jq -n '{christmas: $ARGS.named}' \
  --arg one 'partridge in a "pear" tree' \
  --arg two 'turtle doves'

{
  "christmas": {
    "one": "partridge in a \"pear\" tree",
    "two": "turtle doves"
  }
}
```

Positional arguments:

```
$ jq -n '{numbers: $ARGS.positional}' --args 1 2 3

{
  "numbers": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}
```

Note you can access individual items of the positional array, and that the named arguments are directly available as variables:

```
jq -n '{first: {name: $one, count: $ARGS.positional[0]}, all: $ARGS}' \
  --arg one 'partridge in a "pear" tree' \
  --arg two 'turtle doves' \
  --args 1 2 3

{
  "first": {
    "name": "partridge in a \"pear\" tree",
    "count": "1"
  },
  "all": {
    "positional": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    "named": {
      "one": "partridge in a \"pear\" tree",
      "two": "turtle doves"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI this only works on jq 1.6. Most distros (as of this comment) only distribute 1.4 or 1.5 as part of their official package repos.

https://github.com/antonbabenko/terraform-cost-estimation/issues/5

Answer (score 4):

To add to what [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) and [Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) have already said, you might want to use the `\()` string interpolation syntax in your command. eg.

```
jq -n --arg greeting world '{"hello":"\($greeting)"}'
```

for me this produces

```
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```

Regarding your reply to Jeff's comment, the argument name you choose has to be a valid jq variable name so an arg like `greeting-for-you` won't work but you could use underscores so `greeting_for_you` would be ok.  Or you could use the version Tarun described.

Comment: There is no reason here to use string interpolation as --arg guarantees that the value passed in to jq will alway be a string.  Indeed, the quotation marks around "hello" are not needed either.  Thus writing `{hello: $greeting}` would be just fine.

Comment: You're correct - in this example it's unnecessary.  I wrote it after I saw [Mazzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055637/mazzy)'s comment thinking they might have actually wanted something like `{"hello":"\($greeting)-for-you"}`